# MS SQL: учу триггеры, подскажите ошибку в логике

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, sql, запрос

Добрый день!

Задча: 
триггер не должен позволять отправить  по маршруту тролейбус, если он не пришел еще из прошлого маршрута в депо. Имеем таблицу Shifts (содержит данные по сменам - когда какой тралик ехал по какому маршруту, дату НАЧАЛА смены, и дату ОКОНЧАНИЯ смены, т.е. когда вернулся). Я представляю, все просто - проверяем, если такой-то тралик выехал, т.е. ДАТА ОКОНЧАНИЯ маршрута > Текущей даты, то НЕ ДАЕМ соответственно выпустить этот тралик на новый маршрут (добавить запись в эту таблицу).

```
CREATE TRIGGER LaunchToRoute ON Shifts AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  MAX(S_ShiftEnds) 
    FROM dbo.Shifts 
    WHERE S_Trolleybus = (SELECT TOP(1) S_Trolleybus  FROM INSERTED ORDER BY S_ShiftEnds Desc)
    AND S_ShiftEnds > GETDATE()

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0

    ROLLBACK
    PRINT 'Троллейбус еще не вернулся с рейса и запустить его нельзя!'
END
```

Пробовал по-разному писать условие, но получается что ЛЮБОЙ тралик вообще нельзя выпустить на маршрут (срабатывает триггер), либо позволяет вставить ошибочные данные.
**Подскажите ошибку (в моей логике)**
В текущем состоянии он вообще не дает вставить никаких записей.

Спасибо!

P.S.
Задание и пример я сам себе придумал для обучения. Я считаю что чем дурнее пример, тем полезнее.

Comment: S_Trolleybus - ссылка на поле ID в таблице "Троллейбусы"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 и главная ошибка - нельзя в триггере работать с 1 строкой. не зря `INSERTED` - это таблица. Работайте со всей таблицей.
2 ошибка - агрегационные функции всегда возвращают как минимум 1 строку, поэтому используя max(), вы никогда не получите 0 строк. используйте `count()`.

например, так:

```
if (select count(*) 
      from inserted i
           inner join dbo.shifts s
                   on i.S_Trolleybus = s.S_Trolleybus
     where s.S_ShiftEnds > getdate()) > 0
    begin
        rollback transaction
        raiserror('Троллейбус еще не вернулся с рейса и запустить его нельзя!', 16, 1)
        return
   end
```

Comment: спасибо, minamoto